# Yasnippet snippet for C/C++ while doesn't work correctly

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I have just installed yasnippet package for emacs and am trying to configure snippets. Everything works fine except one particular snipet.

File: ~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20150212.240/snippets/cc-mode/while

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: while
# key: while
# --
while (${1:condition})
{
    $0
}
```

The problem is that when I use the snippet the output is like this:

```
while(condition)
    {

    }
```

I checked if I have the correct file by changing the original while file to this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: while
# key: while
# --
while (${1:condition})
{
    $0;
}
```

(semi-colon added) and the output was:

```
while(condition)
    {
        ;
    }
```

Why my braces have a tab behind them?

Note: Everything else works  fine. For loops work fine, switch works fine, classes work fine... Only the while loop has a problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. It was tricky for someone who just started using emacs like me.

After taking a look [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC) it seems that default c-style is something like this

```
if(foo)
      {
        bar++;
      }
```

so when I pressed tab to use the snippet I also auto formatted the code to the default c style. That's the "gnu" style. To change it to "linux" style just add

```
(setq c-default-style "linux"
      c-basic-offset 4)
```

to your .emacs or init.el file.

Output after changes:

```
if(foo)
{
    bar++;
}
```

It had nothing to do with yasnippet after all.